# If I set a register, completely unrelated memory location gets changed

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev, memory-corruption, gdt

I am creating a 32 bit operating system. I have enabled paging and it works fine, until the kernel_main function returns to the assembly code (which calls the kernel_main function). The assembly code is like this:

```
call kernel_main
jmp $
```

But when bochs runs the `jmp $` instruction, it triple faults with a GPF. Apparently, the code section in the GDT got corrupted.

Bochs output:

```
interrupt(): not accessible or not code segment cs=0x0008
interrupt(): not accessible or not code segment cs=0x0008
interrupt(): not accessible or not code segment cs=0x0008
CPU is in protected mode (active)
CS.mode = 32 bit
SS.mode = 32 bit
EFER   = 0x00000000
| EAX=00000001  EBX=00007d76  ECX=00000014  EDX=00000000
| ESP=0008fff8  EBP=00090000  ESI=000e0000  EDI=0000ffac
| IOPL=0 id vip vif ac vm RF nt of df IF tf sf zf af PF cf
| SEG sltr(index|ti|rpl)     base    limit G D
|  CS:0008( 0001| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
|  DS:00010 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
|  SS:00010 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
|  ES:00010 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
|  FS:00010 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
|  GS:00010 0002| 0|  0) 00000000 ffffffff 1 1
| EIP=00001021 (00001021)
| CR0=0xe0000011 CR2=0x00000000
| CR3=0x00006000 CR4=0x00000000
0008:0000000000001021 (unk. ctxt): jmp .-2  (0x00001021) ; ebfe
exception(): 3rd (13) exception with no resolution, shutdown status is 00h, resetting
bx_pc_system_c::Reset(HARDWARE) called
cpu hardware reset
```

I put a memory watchpoint using the bochs debugger, and found out that the code segment in the GDT gets corrupted at least once. Using the bochs debugger, I found the corrupting instruction:

```
mov ax, DATA_SEG
```

DATA_SEG being the corresponding entry in the GDT. It's value is 0x10.
I want to understand, how does setting a register change a value somewhere else completely?

Thanks for the help!

Some more info I thought would help.
The instruction before `mov ax, DATA_SEG` is `jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm`. `init_pm` is the label right before `mov ax, DATA_SEG`. The full code of that file is below:

```
[bits 16]
switch_to_pm:
    cli ; 1. disable interrupts
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor] ; 2. load the GDT descriptor
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1 ; 3. set 32-bit mode bit in cr0
    mov cr0, eax
    jmp CODE_SEG:init_pm ; 4. far jump by using a different segment

[bits 32]
init_pm: ; we are now using 32-bit instructions
    mov ax, DATA_SEG ; 5. update the segment registers
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    mov ebp, 0x90000 ; 6. update the stack right at the top of the free space
    mov esp, ebp

    call BEGIN_PM ; 7. Call a well-known label with useful code
```

EDIT:

GDT definition:

```
gdt_start: ; don't remove the labels, they're needed to compute sizes and jumps 0x7CCA
    ; the GDT starts with a null 8-byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte
    dd 0x0 ; 4 byte

; GDT for code segment. base = 0x00000000, length = 0xfffff
; for flags, refer to os-dev.pdf document, page 36
gdt_code: 
    dw 0xffff    ; segment length, bits 0-15
    dw 0x0       ; segment base, bits 0-15
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 16-23
    db 10011010b ; flags (8 bits)
    db 11001111b ; flags (4 bits) + segment length, bits 16-19
    db 0x0       ; segment base, bits 24-31

; GDT for data segment. base and length identical to code segment
; some flags changed, again, refer to os-dev.pdf
gdt_data:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_end: ; 0x7CE2

; GDT descriptor
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1 ; size (16 bit), always one less of its true size
    dd gdt_start ; address (32 bit)

; define some constants for later use
CODE_SEG equ gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA_SEG equ gdt_data - gdt_start
```

EDIT 2:

The link to the github is here: https://github.com/aharsi1298/devOS

Comment: What is content of GDT? Have you disabled NMI?

Comment: I will edit the post to add the GDT definition. I haven't disabled NMIs.

Comment: Quick glance at the code. Your GDT seems to be loaded from 0x7c?? in your bootloader. You then load your kernel at 0x1000. You have 4k aligned page tables in your code. Those tables will actually overlap 0x7c00+ memory address and when you call `setup_paging` that memory at 0x7c00+ will be clobbered and that includes your GDT. In essence things like `first_page_table[1024]` are going to be in the memory where your GDT is. `setup_paging` will initialize that as page entries and poof your GDT is wiped out with garbage. You'll want to ensure you no longer have anything of value at 0x7c00+

Comment: The other alternative (but wastes some memory) is to load your kernel somewhere after 0x7c00 instead of 0x1000

Comment: @MichaelPetch in `setup_paging` would changing the array to a pointer work? The pointer would point at some garbage value, like 0x7e00, and it wouldn't matter what got overwritten. `page_directory` would point at 0x7e00, and `first_page_table` would point at 0x8e00.

Comment: Sorry, 0x7e00 won't work. It supposed to be 4096 aligned, so I guess 0x8000 and 0x9000

Comment: Why not just load your kernel at 0x8000 rather than 0x1000? The other option is that after you jump to 0x1000 you load a new GDT that is in the kernel (could place it in kernel_entry.asm) and reload a GDT from memory that won't be clobbered. Then the GDT at 0x7c?? would no longer be a problem because it will no longer be used.

Comment: Sure it would have to be 4k aligned so as you say 0x8000, 0x9000 etc. Something like `unsigned int (*page_directory)[1024] = (unsigned int (*)[1024])0x8000;` and then do something like `(*page_directory)[i] = somevalue;` . One could simplify a bit if you set that up in a linker script. I have to say though this requires you to keep track of things in memory rather than the compiler doing the work.Even if you move the page table and page directory like that if your kernel gets too big again it will run into 0x7c00.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I have tried loading the kernel at 0x8000, but an error comes up. I will be creating another question for that.

Comment: Remember that you put the stack at 0x9000. If you didn't move it out of the way somewhere else you'll clobber it pretty fast and that will likely cause BIOS interrupts to fail. Putting the stack at 0x0000:0x7c00 (below the bootloader) rather than 0x9000 should work until you get into protected mode.